# Exercise with definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I found an exercise in a calculus book which says:
Let $a$ be real. Prove that there is no positive and continuous function $f(x)$ in $[0, 1]$ such that
$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1, \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=a, \int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx=a^2$.
I only got that $a$ is between $0$ and $1$. Is there any obvious trick that I missed?

Comment: Let me point you to [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). The wiki page is full of informations but the most relevant is the [L2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) case.

Comment: @WhatsUp Yes, I tried to apply Cauchy Schwarz, but without much success. How to use it?

Comment: In the discrete case, we have $\left(\sum \sqrt{a_i b_i}\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum a_i\right)\left(\sum b_i\right)$ for positive numbers $a_i, b_i$, and we know exactly **when** the equality holds. Now integration is just some sort of sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there exists such function $f$.

Consider the integral
$$I=\int_0^1(x-a)^2f(x)\,\textrm dx$$
Since the integrand is positive and continuous, we must have $I>0$. Now, by binomial expansion and the linearity of integral, we get
$$I=\int_0^1x^2f(x)\,\textrm dx-2a\int_0^1xf(x)\,\textrm dx +a^2\int_0^1f(x)\,\textrm dx$$
Using the given values, we get
$$I=a^2-2a\cdot a + a^2=0$$
which is a contradiction. Thus, no such function exists. $\square$

**Note**

The trick is certainly "not obvious", and the motivation for the integral $I$ comes from observing that we have three terms with $x^0$, $x^1$ and $x^2$. It still might seem very unmotivated, but all it comes from problem solving.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)